# How can I specify the launch image duration in trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

The iPhone launch image shows up too short right now and I wanted to extend the duration.
Is there a way to specify this in the config.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: as of platform version v1.4.20 you can control the launchimage visibility (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-20).

The reason for this is that some UI frameworks (notably Sencha) take some time to initialise after the page has loaded. All the advice below about not using the launchimage as anything but a lightweight "holding notice" for you app still applies.

---

Original answer:

No, we've not allowed configuration of this type with Trigger.io: the reason is that Apple's guidelines suggest the launch image should only be used to smooth application startup - not to present any kind of branding or splash screen experience.

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf:

> Avoid using your launch image as an opportunity to provide:
>
> - An “application entry experience,” such as a splash screen
> - An About window
> - Branding elements, unless they are a static part of your application’s first screen